# Pivot table automatically filters through today's date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table whose fields include "Due Date".  I need to filter it so it shows only the dates up through "today".

Currently, the Due Date field is in the "Filters" box. The filter makes me choose the dates one at a time.

If I move the Due Date to the Rows or Columns box, then the drop-down gives me the "Date Filters" option. Here I can choose, for instance, "Before..." followed by tomorrow's date. That will do in a pinch, but my client would rather have it change automatically every day.

VBA is not permitted.

EDIT: The data looks like this:

```
LOCATION   DUE_DATE   STATUS
Anchorage  10/1/23     New
Anchorage  9/20/23     Pending
Birmingham 10/30/23    Completed
Birmingham 1/1/24      New
Chicago    10/1/23     Completed
```

As I said, I want to filter DUE_DATE so that it displays dates up through "Today" -- or, failing that, up through the date displayed in a specific cell.

I realize now that I'd also like to filter STATUS to display everything but "Completed".

Comment: It can definitely be achieved if you load the data into the Excel Data Model/PowerPivot or by adding some formula driven fields to your source data. Either way some sample data would make it easier to explain how to do it